# Subsetting rows in a data.frame() by multiple criteria in single column using library(dplyr), filter()

Tags: r

I am trying to filter a data.frame based on two criteria in the first column. here is my original data table:

`df=rbind(l2a,l3a,l5b);df`

which gives the following output:

`line      immci      log10ci clutch flask num
1   L2a  1.9928984  0.299485154      g  xiii   1
2   L2a  2.0844090  0.318982944      g  xiii   2
3   L2a  1.5264288  0.183676540      g  xiii   3
4   L2a  0.9567779 -0.019188860      g  xiii   4
5   L2a  1.6149111  0.208148610      g  xiii   5
6   L2a  1.8939134  0.277360108      g  xiii   6
7   L2a  1.2506454  0.097134194      g  xiii   7
8   L2a  1.9859786  0.297974563      g  xiii   8
9   L2a  1.7384858  0.240171153      g  xiii   9
10  L2a  1.4590863  0.164080984      g  xiii  10
11  L2a  0.4699034 -0.327991426      h    xv  11
12  L2a  1.5271860  0.183891935      h    xv  12
13  L2a  0.6774155 -0.169144894      h    xv  13
14  L2a  1.6782264  0.224850542      h    xv  14
15  L2a  1.0197556  0.008496103      h    xv  15
16  L2a  1.3849784  0.141443000      h    xv  16
17  L2a  1.6152929  0.208251280      h    xv  17
18  L2a  1.5214085  0.182245839      h    xv  18
19  L2a  1.2306993  0.090151968      h    xv  19
20  L2a  2.4760294  0.393755793      h    xv  20
21  L2a  0.2660571 -0.575025122      i  xvii  21
22  L2a  1.8511805  0.267448775      i  xvii  22
23  L2a  0.9735272 -0.011651922      i  xvii  23
24  L2a  1.3016773  0.114503326      i  xvii  24
25  L2a  1.0381621  0.016265152      i  xvii  25
26  L2a  2.2904514  0.359921077      i  xvii  26
27  L2a  1.7535583  0.243920200      i  xvii  27
28  L2a  1.9884998  0.298525551      i  xvii  28
29  L2a  2.8867197  0.460404617      i  xvii  29
30  L2a  1.1027367  0.042471840      i  xvii  30
31  L3a  2.7755014  0.443341458      a     i   1
32  L3a  3.3246253  0.521742701      a     i   2
33  L3a  2.6471891  0.422784960      a     i   3
34  L3a  3.1020086  0.491643000      a     i   4
35  L3a  3.4601116  0.539090102      a     i   5
36  L3a  2.2464903  0.351504556      a     i   6
37  L3a  2.1724638  0.336952556      a     i   7
38  L3a  2.2577228  0.353670618      a     i   8
39  L3a  3.2253183  0.508572578      a     i   9
40  L3a  3.0630622  0.486155818      a     i  10
41  L3a  2.3777851  0.376172593      b    ii  11
42  L3a  0.8454347 -0.072919938      b    ii  12
43  L3a  1.3209917  0.120900088      b    ii  13
44  L3a  0.8454347 -0.072919938      b    ii  14
45  L3a  0.8454347 -0.072919938      b    ii  15
46  L3a  1.0567934  0.023990075      b    ii  16
47  L3a  1.4090578  0.148928811      b    ii  17
48  L3a  1.7172892  0.234843440      b    ii  18
49  L3a  6.3407601  0.802141325      b    ii  19
50  L3a  1.0567934  0.023990075      b    ii  20
51  L3a  1.3612015  0.133922403      c   iii  21
52  L3a  2.0879623  0.319722648      c   iii  22
53  L3a  1.6070421  0.206027251      c   iii  23
54  L3a  1.6739557  0.223743962      c   iii  24
55  L3a  2.7192951  0.434456346      c   iii  25
56  L3a  2.0894176  0.320025246      c   iii  26
57  L3a  1.6089163  0.206533449      c   iii  27
58  L3a  2.3979239  0.379835395      c   iii  28
59  L3a  1.5228053  0.182644373      c   iii  29
60  L3a  1.2916652  0.111149956      c   iii  30
61  L5b  4.8973579  0.689961841      g   xiv   1
62  L5b  5.8659429  0.768337829      g   xiv   2
63  L5b  1.3256006  0.122412700      g   xiv   3
64  L5b  2.1995151  0.342326950      g   xiv   4
65  L5b  3.4130407  0.533141466      g   xiv   5
66  L5b  4.1081677  0.613648164      g   xiv   6
67  L5b  4.4651811  0.649839073      g   xiv   7
68  L5b  1.6466150  0.216592073      g   xiv   8
69  L5b  1.7674675  0.247351437      g   xiv   9
70  L5b  1.7054511  0.231839271      g   xiv  10
71  L5b 17.3092190  1.238277472      h   xvi  11
72  L5b  5.8925001  0.770299597      h   xvi  12
73  L5b  7.6929862  0.886094954      h   xvi  13
74  L5b  7.8566668  0.895238334      h   xvi  14
75  L5b 11.1957502  1.049053198      h   xvi  15
76  L5b 11.0975418  1.045226790      h   xvi  16
77  L5b 11.6510797  1.066366173      h   xvi  17
78  L5b  5.1068334  0.708151690      h   xvi  18
79  L5b  6.1687110  0.790194426      h   xvi  19
80  L5b  5.2295938  0.718467959      h   xvi  20
81  L5b  4.9864112  0.697788089      i xviii  21
82  L5b  1.4543699  0.162674888      i xviii  22
83  L5b  4.8223845  0.683261836      i xviii  23
84  L5b  4.4953252  0.652761120      i xviii  24
85  L5b 11.8773545  1.074719717      i xviii  25
86  L5b  5.7265816  0.757895455      i xviii  26
87  L5b  3.7722720  0.576603002      i xviii  27
88  L5b  3.9038351  0.591491463      i xviii  28
89  L5b  2.7968653  0.446671544      i xviii  29
90  L5b  2.4542493  0.389918669      i xviii  30`

I would like to produce a data frame that only has the rows that contain "L3a" and "L5b". so far I have tried the following:

`filter(imm,line==c('L3a','L5b'))`

which produces:

`line      immci     log10ci clutch flask num
1   L3a  2.7755014  0.44334146      a     i   1
2   L3a  2.6471891  0.42278496      a     i   3
3   L3a  3.4601116  0.53909010      a     i   5
4   L3a  2.1724638  0.33695256      a     i   7
5   L3a  3.2253183  0.50857258      a     i   9
6   L3a  2.3777851  0.37617259      b    ii  11
7   L3a  1.3209917  0.12090009      b    ii  13
8   L3a  0.8454347 -0.07291994      b    ii  15
9   L3a  1.4090578  0.14892881      b    ii  17
10  L3a  6.3407601  0.80214133      b    ii  19
11  L3a  1.3612015  0.13392240      c   iii  21
12  L3a  1.6070421  0.20602725      c   iii  23
13  L3a  2.7192951  0.43445635      c   iii  25
14  L3a  1.6089163  0.20653345      c   iii  27
15  L3a  1.5228053  0.18264437      c   iii  29
16  L5b  5.8659429  0.76833783      g   xiv   2
17  L5b  2.1995151  0.34232695      g   xiv   4
18  L5b  4.1081677  0.61364816      g   xiv   6
19  L5b  1.6466150  0.21659207      g   xiv   8
20  L5b  1.7054511  0.23183927      g   xiv  10
21  L5b  5.8925001  0.77029960      h   xvi  12
22  L5b  7.8566668  0.89523833      h   xvi  14
23  L5b 11.0975418  1.04522679      h   xvi  16
24  L5b  5.1068334  0.70815169      h   xvi  18
25  L5b  5.2295938  0.71846796      h   xvi  20
26  L5b  1.4543699  0.16267489      i xviii  22
27  L5b  4.4953252  0.65276112      i xviii  24
28  L5b  5.7265816  0.75789545      i xviii  26
29  L5b  3.9038351  0.59149146      i xviii  28
30  L5b  2.4542493  0.38991867      i xviii  30`

As you can see, it only grabs every other row of the data that I actually want, and I can't figure out why. I have also tried using all(), any(), &, and |. Can anyone provide some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I should add, that "imm" is my original data set. "df" is a data set I created to ask this problem. "imm" is a data set that contains many rows.

Comment: You need `%in%` instead of `==`.

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Thanks so much aosmith!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `filter` as

```
df[df$line %in% c("L3a", "L5b"), ]
```

will do the trick.